# Properly close a hidden window in access 2003 with Macro or VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003

How do you PROPERLY close a HIDDEN form / window in Access 2003 WITHOUT going to the top menu and choosing unhide and closing it manually?

There is only one method that I'm aware of (because I don't know VBA... yet) and that is to make a macro that closes the window/form by name using the Close action. But, when I do this, it gives me an error and says it can't find the named object. (Yet, if I check the unhide window list, said window has indeed been closed.)

This is really irritating because apparently it's closing the hidden window, then throwing an error saying that it can't find the object (which of course, messes up the macro sequence).

Is there a more "correct" way to close a hidden window?

> So, the answer is...... I was encountering an ID-10-T error. I was referencing the hidden form AGAIN after it was closed, which, because of the instantaneous nature of the code execution in general, I missed that fact...
>
> ...problem solved. PEBKAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested these in Access 2010 and they both seem to work fine on a hidden form:

*From a Macro...*

Action: **CloseWindow**
Object Type: **Form**
ObjectName: **AgentsForm**
Save: **No**

*From VBA code...*

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "AgentsForm", acSaveNo
```

Comment: After some more testing, I managed to do it with a macro, but it seems like the hidden window has to be closed by the same macro it was opened by or else it won't do it. Not sure if this is a 2003 thing or what.

Comment: @DjM Maybe Access 2003 is a bit different in that regard, but for my tests in Access 2010 I just opened the form from the VBA Immediate Window using `DoCmd.OpenForm "AgentsForm",acNormal,,,,acHidden`. Also, I've never had a problem with the VBA `DoCmd` variant since... ever.